# Probability mass function of number of emails processed by my secretary?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Suppose I have a secretary who filters the emails addressed to me. To process an email, the secretary would have it forwarded to me with probability $p$, otherwise she would delete it forever. The secretary deals with each email independently.

Suppose I was forwarded $c$ emails within a given hour. **What is the probability mass function of the total number of emails $X$ my secretary has processed within that hour?** Note that

- the forwarded emails are not necessarily consecutive
- the secretary does not necessarily stop after forwarding $c$ emails: theoretically she could have processed and deleted an additional 1,000,000,000 emails after that

My gut says the pmf is the following, the probability of the secretary forwarding $c$ out of $n$ emails she processed:

$$
\Pr(X=n) = \binom{n}{c} p^c (1-p)^{n-c}
$$

However, I was reminded that a pmf must satisfy this condition:

$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \Pr(X=n) = 1
$$

When I used [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) (cross-checked with Python) to perform a quick computation with $p = 0.05$ and $c = 5$, this pmf does not satisfy the above condition!

```
?  p=0.05; c=5; suminf(N=c, binomial(N,c) * p^c * (1-p)^(N-c))
%17 = 19.999999999999999999999999999999999906
```

That is, it appears that with the above parameters we have

$$
\sum_{n=5}^\infty \Pr(X=n) \stackrel{?}{=} 20 \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{p} \ne 1
$$

**What am I missing**? I have been confused by this (self-created) problem for a while now.

Comment: I am not quite sure frankly, but if I were you I would read about the negative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the random total number of emails received in one hour.  Let $F$ be the random number of forwarded emails in the same time period.  Then the conditional random variable $$F \mid N \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N, p)$$ with $$\Pr[F = c \mid N] = \binom{N}{c} p^c (1-p)^{N-c}, \quad c \in \{0, 1, \ldots, N\}.$$  What you want to find is the PMF of $N$ conditioned on observing $F = c$, namely $$\Pr[N = n \mid F = c] = \frac{\Pr[F = c \mid N = n]\Pr[N = n]}{\Pr[F = c]}$$ by Bayes' rule.  Now it becomes evident why you are having difficulties:  without specifying the *prior distribution* for $N$, i.e. $\Pr[N = n]$, it is not possible to uniquely determine the posterior distribution given $c$ observed forwarded emails.  The denominator, $\Pr[F = c]$, is easily computed via the law of total probability from knowledge of $\Pr[N = n]$, e.g. $$\Pr[F = c] = \sum_{n=c}^\infty \Pr[F = c \mid N = n]\Pr[N = n].$$  So the only piece that is missing is the prior distribution for $N$.

A commonly used model for a counting process is to assume $$N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda),$$ with $$\Pr[N = n] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}, \quad n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\},$$ for some rate parameter $\lambda$ representing in your case the mean intensity of email arrivals in one hour.  If we use this prior distribution, we then find $$\Pr[F = c \mid N = n] \Pr[N = n] = \binom{n}{c} p^c (1-p)^{n-c} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} = \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^c e^{-\lambda} \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^n}{c! (n-c)!}. $$
 Therefore, the kernel of the posterior distribution is a location-shifted Poisson with location shift $c$ and intensity $\lambda^* = \lambda(1-p)$:  $$\Pr[N = n \mid F = c] = e^{-\lambda(1-p)} \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{n-c}}{(n-c)!}, \quad n \in \{c, c+1, c+2, \ldots \}.$$  The formal details of this derivation are left as an exercise for the reader.  But note that even in this special case of using a Poisson prior, we still are underdetermined in the sense that we could have infinitely many choices for the mean intensity of email arrivals.